# List and Arrays

Tags: c#

I have 5 Values to add to a list.  How can I make it cleaner with fewer lines of codes?

```
String[] values= new String[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
 Values= new List<ValuesRow>();
        foreach (var item in values)
        {               
            Values.Add(new ValuesRow
            {
                Name = item,
                ID = 0
            });
        }

public class ValuesRow
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also initialize the list like this:

```
Values = new List<ValuesRow> { new ValuesRow { Name = "AA", ID = 0}, 
                               new ValuesRow { Name = "BB", ID = 0}
                             };
```

Answer (score 6):

If the list doesn't exists as in your sample :

```
var names = new[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
var Values = names.Select(name => new ValuesRow { Name = name, ID = "0" }).ToList();
```

otherwise

```
var names = new[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
var newElements = names.Select(name => new ValuesRow { Name = name, ID = "0" });
Values.AddRange(newElements);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to add **only** 5 records which are known at compile time with less code you can try this:

```
        var Values = new List<ValuesRow>
        {
            new ValuesRow{Name="Value1", ID="1"}
            new ValuesRow{Name="Value2", ID="2"}
            new ValuesRow{Name="Value3", ID="3"}
            new ValuesRow{Name="Value4", ID="4"}
            new ValuesRow{Name="Value5", ID="5"}
        };
```

Comment: This could also be a little bit shorter by implementing a constructor on ValuesRow in that case you can just use: new ValuesRow("Value1", "1")

Comment: this is a long way. you can use loop for it.

Comment: @Serkan It is your personal opinion.

Comment: every comment is a personal opinion I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AddRange` method or create new list from array.

```
Values.AddRange(values.Select((value, index) => new ValuesRow {Name = value, ID = index.ToString() }));
```

Comment: Or just use the array as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ValuesRow> vR = new List<ValuesRow>();

foreach(string item in values)
{
vR.Add(new ValuesRow {item,"0"});
}
```

Do you want to make like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values= new String[] { "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF" };
var Values = new List<ValuesRow>();
Values.AddRange(values.Select(v => new ValuesRow() {Name = v, ID = "0"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using an object initialiser, which works like this:

```
        var values = new List<ValuesRow>
                         {
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "AA"},
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "BB"},
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "CC"},
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "DD"},
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "EE"},
                             new ValuesRow {ID = "0", Name = "FF"}
                         };
```